# Bitmap animation possible or not

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, touch-event

Is it possible to set *water ripple effect* in bitmap **`onTouchEvent`** method?

```
@Override
public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
}
```

If yes then How?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case you have an ImageView and after user clicks this ImageView you want to display the ripple effect you don't need to use the onTouchEvent method. If that's the case answer to this can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393684/set-ripple-effect-on-image-view) StackOverflow question. I'll summarize the answer below.

Wrap your ImageView in FrameLayout and set your ripple drawable to the FrameLayout's *android:forgeround* attribute in XML. You can find code sample and also workaround for Android SDK versions lower than 21 in the linked answer.

Comment: thanks but i have put ripple effect on touch of live wallpaper not on imageview