# how to apply ripple effect on textview when already background set

Tags: android, material-design, rippledrawable

I want to apply ripple effect when any item click. But I can't apply each and every item

```
android:background="@color/tabColor"
```

background already set so how to use following code

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

```
<TextView    
            android:id="@+id/mistake_btn_tv"    
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/tabColor"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="none"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_20"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="monospace"/>
```

I expect both are working there, my background "tabColor" and also ripple effect

Comment: try `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` https://stackoverflow.com/a/34128965/7666442

Comment: Add the ripple-like this I have used this before : [set ripple effect ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393684/set-ripple-effect-on-image-view/35753159#35753159)

Comment: but i have already added background so now how to add ripple

Comment: The solutions provided in answers are enough to create ripple effect. But it will only appear when you `setOnClickListener` or make the `view` clickable.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a custom `drawable` file for **ripple effect**. Here I am sharing code with you. Just implement that code. Hope it will work fine.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/colorAccent"
    tools:ignore="NewApi">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/gray_text"/>
            <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

and set it to **background**:-

```
  android:background="@drawable/border_ripple_gray"
```

Answer (score 6):

You should  use `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` for ripple effect.

Comment: Your textview should be clickable for ripple to work. Either set `android:clickable="true"` or set a click listener in code.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it - why should one "use" that given stuff?

Answer (score 2):

when you have set background already do this in your [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) XML code.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

use this library for best ripple effect..
     [link](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your style.xml

```
<item name="android:colorControlHighlight" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/backgroundWhite</item>
```

and use view property:-

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score -1):

I am late to the party but above solutions are not working for me. So I am using `MaterialButton` like this,

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/padding_8dp"
        android:text="Clickable Text"
        android:textColor="your text color"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        app:rippleColor="ripple effect color" />
```

Here, `style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"` and `app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"` will make this button as transparent background so that it will look like TextView and everything else will be done automatically.